# Do lots of fonts affect the (overall) performance of my system?

Tags: macos, font

I got lots of fonts *installed* and *active*. Sometimes I feel like a large amount of fonts is slowing down my applications, especially when they offer font choices (e.g. Photoshop, Pages, …). The drop down is appearing with delay or a beachball of death is popping up for some seconds.

But that's just about specific applications… What about OS X in general? How much do many active/installed fonts slow down the system?